# Did I fry my drives?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, power-supply

So, I bought a new PSU, a eVGA G3 750w, previously I had a Corsair CX750M, but still everything worked OK.

After installing the new PSU, the PC boots OK, goes to the BIOS and I see no drives there, I used to have a SSD and HDD.

After a bit of digging on the reason why this was happening, I discovered that I made the mistake of reusing the old Corsair power cables that powered my drives, with the new PSU I acquired.

After examining the distribution of the sockets, yup, they are different. Then I smelled a strong burnt plastic smell from the SSD.

So, it's safe to say that I fried both my drives right?, I then changed the cable for the proper one, tried a different SSD that I had somewhere and it was recognized by the BIOS just fine. Also tried both those drives on a different PC and they are indeed dead.

Just curious as to why on earth would the standards change, and fry drives in the process.

Comment: How were the cables different?

Comment: There isn't a standard for power supply cables in regards to the modular ones and the end that plugs in to the power supply. Yes the drives are fried.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz they  have different voltage distribution.
Appleoddity, mark it as answered if you can, I will take it as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did fry my drives :), wrong pin configuration.